# Descodificar texto hexadecimal en bytearray y convertirlo a cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy recibiendo, por un *socket*, unas credenciales de usuario codificadas en hexadecimal.

Ahora, tengo que usarlas en una función que solo admite cadenas como argumento. Y dicha función espera las credenciales **en texto plano**, no en hexadecimal.

He intentado

```
recido = bytearray( b'4a4b4c' )
texto = str( bytes.fromhex( recibido ) )
```

> TypeError: fromhex() argument must be str, not bytearray

Y tambien

```
recido = bytearray( b'4a4b4c' )
texto = str( bytes.fromhex( str( recibido ) ) )
```

> ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

#### ¿ Como obtengo el texto real, descodificando el *hex*, en una cadena ?

<sub>**Nota**: en el código de ejemplo, `4a4b4c == JKL`</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
recido = b'4a4b4c'.decode('utf-8')
texto = bytes.fromhex(recido).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Los caracteres en hex no los obtengo de una cadena, sino de un bytearray. Adaptándolo a mi código, obtengo el mismo error: `non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex()`.

Comment: Puedes hacer ```recido = b'4a4b4c'.decode('utf-8')``` y luego le pasas ```recido``` a ```fromhex()```

Comment: Pues ponlo en la respuesta :-)